# Is EnableViewStateMAC=true compulsory for ViewStateEncryption in an ASP.Net Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption, viewstate

I'm currently fixing some Security issues in our ASP.net website application.

One of the issue was that the `ViewState` was not encrypted.

So I did check on StackOverFlow and elsewhere on how to encrypt the viewState, and I did it using the `<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />` and adding a 3DES machinekey like this `<machineKey validation="3DES" />` in Web.config .

**I would like to know if the `"EnableViewStateMAC=true"` is also compulsorily necessary?** since this was mentioned in some of the suggested solutions I had found online. 
But, on my checks I found the encryption is working even without this.

*[NOTE: I had to do these changes at an application level (Web.config) since making individual page changes is not a practical solution for this application.]*

Comment: If you're going to encrypt your ViewState, it's a good idea to MAC it as well, to detect an attacker tampering with the data. Encryption alone doesn't provide integrity of messages.

Answer (score 19):

Do not ever set EnableViewStateMac to false, even if encryption is enabled.  The MAC guarantees that the client cannot maliciously tamper with the contents of ViewState.  (Encryption by itself isn't sufficient to guarantee this; the MAC is necessary.)

The EnableViewStateMac property will be removed in a future version of the product since there is no valid reason to set it to 'false'.

Comment: What if you persisted the ViewState to a database so that only an ID is passed through to the client and there's no way for them to see the ViewState?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  EnableViewStateMac protects more than just ViewState, so it should *never* be set to false.  THERE ARE NO EXCEPTIONS TO THIS RULE.

Comment: And... 10 months later @Levi just announced on Twitter that even if you set it to false, it will be ignored. Like Levi said, no exceptions and now if your code depend on this, it will break. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just in case:

> **Starting with ASP.NET 4.5.2, the runtime enforces EnableViewStateMac = true**

more details here: [ASP.NET 4.5.2 and EnableViewStateMac](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/07/asp-net-4-5-2-and-enableviewstatemac.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to note that as of September 2014

All versions of the ASP.NET runtime 1.1 - 4.5.2 now forbid setting

> <%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" %>

and

> <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac.aspx

Comment: Do I need to fix anything if my EnableViewStateMac="true" ?

Answer (score 0):

It 'll be problem When You host multi server. Because Machine Keys are different.

IF your project runs  on single machine. EnableViewStateMAC=true is safely.

Using enableViewStateMac requires that successive requests be forwarded to the same server (i.e. server affinity).  This feature is used to help prevent tampering of a page's view state; however, it does so based on an auto-generated validation key on the current server.  From this key, a message authentication code (MAC) is generated and sent in the ViewState back to the browser.  The problem is that if a POST back is performed and goes to a different server, you will get a nice little error message saying “Corrupt View State“.

To fix this, you can either set enableViewStateMac to false in the  element or specify a common value for the validationKey attribute in the  element across all servers (in the farm).

By the way, documentation says that this is OFF by default.  That is incorrect!  Go check machine.config!

Comment: Hi halit, 
Thanks for the response. 

The thing i would like to know is if it is absolutely necessary for me to use the EnableViewStateMAC=true??? Or isn't the above changes which i have done enough for me to encrypt my viewState??

I do not wish to EnableViewStateMAC if its not necessary.

Comment: You 'll decide. IF you don't enabled it. ThirdParty tools can decode. Your viewSate. http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx

Comment: Ex. IF you store user list which includes passwords in viewstate. They can decode and see passwords.

Comment: You should NEVER EVER EVER store a list of users and their passwords in ViewState. You should NEVER even be able to see their raw passwords.

Comment: Password is only example. :) He shouldn't store.