# Difference between EnableViewStateMac and ViewStateEncryptionMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

While I was going through the MSDN Link for EnableViewStateMac: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , it says:

```
A view-state MAC is an encrypted version of the hidden variable that a
page's view state is persisted
```

However, setting the `ViewStateEncryptionMode` to `always` also encrypts the view state. So to me, right now, it seems both the Page's proprty are encrypting ViewState.

Can you please help me understand what is actually the difference between the two: ViewStateEncryptionMode & EnableViewStateMac ?

Apart from encrypting the ViewState, what else are they doing ?

Comment: hope [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14210118/1849444) help you

Comment: @teo van kot: answer did helped me understand few things. Can you also point me to some more links if you have any. Will be great!

Answer (score 0):

**EnableViewStateMac** used to ensure that the viewstate for a page has not been tampered with.

- ASP.NET raises an error (Validation of viewstate MAC failed) if it detects that there has been a change in the value of viewstate that was sent to the browser